# What would cause this JavaScript Regex titleize performance?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

These `toTitleCase` functions *rougly* do the same thing.

But I'm curious to know why `v1_toTitleCase` would be faster than `v5_toTitleCase`?

And why `v6_toTitleCase` is faster than `v3_toTitleCase`? Since this is practically the same thing but `v3_toTitleCase` is specific to spaces.

I'd like to get the same performance as `v2_toTitleCase` but don't want to uppercase inputs like `(hello` => `(Hello`.

```
const input = "hello world! how are you today? Upper case Everything.";

const v1_toTitleCase = (str) => {
  if (!str) {
    return str;
  }

  const parts = str.toLowerCase()
    .split(' ');

  return parts.map(part => {
    if (!part?.length) {
      return part;
    }
    const firstLetter = part[0].toUpperCase();
    const remainingLetters = part.substr(1, part.length);

    return firstLetter + remainingLetters;
  })
    .join(' ');
}

const RegexFirstLetterOfWords = /(?:^| )(\S)/g;

const v2_toTitleCase = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase()); 
};

const v3_toTitleCase = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/(?:^| )(\S)/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase()); 
};

const v4_toTitleCase = (str) => {
    return str.replace(RegexFirstLetterOfWords, letter => letter.toUpperCase());    
};

const v5_toTitleCase = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/(?:^| )(\w)/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase()); 
};

// underscore.string implementation.
const v6_toTitleCase = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/(?:^|\s|-)\S/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase());    
};
```

Here's a [performance runner](https://jsbench.me/neldvvtnd5/4).

Thoughts?

Is there a faster regex that I'm unaware of like `\b` but for splitting text by whitespace?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Did you check `str.replace(/(?<!\S)[a-z]/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase())` ?

Comment: Combining the approaches in v2 and v3 gives `/(?:^| )[a-z]/g` which is about 4% slower than v2 (vs 8% slower for v1). The negative lookbehind version is about the same speed as v1.

Comment: Splitting out the first character as a special case, we get `str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).replace(/ [a-z]/g, letter => letter.toUpperCase())` which benchmarks about 3% faster than v2 for me.